# Making an NSMutableString transformation without leaking memory?

Tags: memory-management, nsstring

I have this function within an iPhone project Objective C class.

While it's correct in terms of the desired functionality, after a few calls, it crashes into the debugger.

So I think it's a case of bad memory management, but I'm not sure where.

```
- (NSString *)stripHtml:(NSString *)originalText {
// remove all html tags (<.*>) from the originalText string
NSMutableString *strippedText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

BOOL appendFlag = YES;
for( int i=0; i<[originalText length]; i++ ) {
    NSString *current = [originalText substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    if( [current isEqualTo:@"<"] )
        appendFlag = NO;
    if( appendFlag ) 
        [strippedText appendString:current];
    if( [current isEqualTo:@">"] )
        appendFlag = YES;
}

NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithString:strippedText];
[strippedText release];
return newText;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Every time you iterate over your for loop, you're allocating a new NSString.  While these NSStrings are autoreleased, they won't actually be released until after all the processing of your last input is finished.  In the meantime, you'll allocate a potentially infinite amount of memory.  The solution is to create your own autorelease pool and drain it every trip through the for loop.  It'll look something like this:

```
BOOL appendFlag = YES;
for( int i=0; i<[originalText length]; i++ ) {    
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
// rest of for loop body
[pool drain];
}
```

That'll free up the memory used by your current pointer right away.